# Using Array#shift with square brackets (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, shift

I'm reading through Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby and I came upon this code example wherein he adds a class variable and an instance method to the String class.  The idea is that, given a string of an alien name, like "Paij-Ree", we could run something like

```
"Paij-ree".determine_significance # returns "Personal AM"
```

Here is the code:

```
class String

  @@syllables = [
    { 'Paij' => 'Personal',
      'Gonk' => 'Business',
      'Blon' => 'Slave',
      'Stro' => 'Master',
      'Wert' => 'Father',
      'Onnn' => 'Mother' },
    { 'ree'  => 'AM',
      'plo'  => 'PM' }
  ]

  # a method to determine what a certain
  # name of his means

  def determine_significance

    parts = self.split( '-' )

    syllables = @@syllables.dup

    signif = parts.collect do |p|
      syllables.shift[p]
    end

    signif.join( ' ' )
  end

end
```

My question:  What is going on in the collect block where there are square brackets after the Array#shift method?  I've only been able to find examples where it is used like this:

```
letters = ['a','b','c']
letters.shift  # returns "a"
```

What's going on here?

```
syllables.shift[p]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's doing exactly that. `@@syllables` is an array of hashes, so it shifts the first value out of the array, which is a hash. Then it accesses it using the split string as the key.

`self.split( '-' )` returns a string array and that is mapped over with `collect` to replace it with the value in the hash.

The important part is that the array is duplicated to avoid destroying the original `@@syllables` so you can shift the duplicate.

Comment: Ohh.  Also looking at it again, it's a little easier to see what going on if you write it like this: `syllables.shift.[](p)`.  So `syllables.shift` returns the first hash in the syllables array and then `.[](p)` returns the value associated with the `p` key in that hash.  `.collect` then adds that to the `signif` array!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: not so much adds as substitutes it in a new array. but yeah thats the idea

Answer (score -1):

This is what is going on:

```
parts = self.split('-')
```

Is turning a string to:

```
['Paij', 'ree'] # an Array
```

The next block in question:

```
signif = parts.collect do |p|
  syllables.shift[p]
end
```

passes in each instance in the array `['Paij', 'ree']` `(parts variable)` to the block and returns the matched value from the `@@syllables` variable.